# Default DICOM encoding without Specific Character Set

Tags: encoding, character-encoding, dicom

If a DICOM file does not define a `Specific Character Set (0008,0005)`, what character set does it use by default? Is ASCII the default encoding for DICOM files?

**TL;DR**

A DICOM file contains German *ä* in one of the tags, but the file does not specify any character set. I assume that in this case the file is allowed to contain only ASCII symbols (the default character set) and report this file as invalid. Before I submit my change, I want to make sure that I understood DICOM correctly.

Comment: How can you know (with certainty) that it is an ä without actually knowing what the character encoding is? In /most/ single byte character encodings, the ä is represented with the same byte value. However, that is not guaranteed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As specified in the Dicom Data Structures and Encoding

**6.1.2.5.4 Levels of Implementation and Initial Designation**

a) Attribute Specific Character Set (0008,0005) not present:

7-bit code
Implementation level: ISO 2022 Level 1 - Elementary 7-bit code (code-level identifier 1)

Initial designation: ISO-IR 6 (ASCII) as G0.
Code Extension shall not be used

Reference:

- http://dicom.nema.org/medical/dicom/current/output/chtml/part05/chapter_6.html#sect_6.1.2.5.4

Comment: I read this part. What do designation and code extension mean?

Comment: Well, in my understanding "initial designation" means "use as default". To better understand the code extension you may read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_2022

Comment: Yes, ascii is the default.

Answer (score 2):

To add to answer by JonnyQ, DICOM standard also defines mechanisms when confronted with character sets that are unknown to implementations or unsupported (see PS 3.5 section 6.1.2.3). Implementations can print or display such characters by replacing all unknown characters with the four characters "\nnn", where "nnn" is the three digit octal representation of each byte.

An example given in the standard for an ASCII based machine as follows:

Character String: Günther

Encoded representation: 04/07 15/12 06/14 07/04 06/08 06/05 07/02

ASCII based machine: G\374nther

Implementations may also encounter Control Characters which they have no means to print or display.
Application may print or display such Control Characters by replacing the Control Character with the
four characters “\nnn”, where “nnn” is the three digit octal representation of each byte.

Comment: If a char set is unknown, there is no point in trying to interpret any binary value as a character. Simply because some of the code points exist in ascii or one of the iso-8859 variants is meaningless. Similarly, if code points are encountered which are not valid for the char set/encoding which is (supposedly) in use, this seems to indicate that the actual char encoding in use is unknown, making it impossible to state with certainty that any of the code points can accurately be interpreted. Effectively these guidelines are only useful for valid code points which cannot be displayed.